# Fitting A Semi-Circle Between Three Lines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have the general situation illustrated below. I know angles $\Theta_{1}, \Theta_{2}$ and line lengths $A$, $B$ and $C$, (where $A = a_{1} + a_{2}$ etc.). I'm trying to calculate the largest semi-circle I can fit on line $B$ (i.e., calculate r), that will (always?) be tangent to line $A$ and $C$ when the angles are acute.

[image: General Situation]

So I think:
$$
r = \frac{B.sin\Theta_{1}  .sin\Theta_{2} } { sin\Theta_{1} + sin\Theta_{2} }
$$

For the cases where $A > a_{1}$ and $C > c_{1}$ (meaning A is longer than the theoretical tangent point at the angle $\Theta_{1}$ etc.). But what if $A$ was very short? Does $r$ simply become the distance to the end point of $A$? And how do I 'know' when this is the case mathematically?

**EDIT: To add some clarification...**

- This is part of a larger effort to find the largest semi-circle that will fit inside an arbitrary closed polygon.
- The lines illustrated are thus three consecutive segments of that polygon
- They may be any angle and length, and don't form a triangle unless my polygon is a triangle.
- Clearly, if the angle at either or both ends is larger than $\pi$, the semi-circle can go right to that vertex and isn't impinged upon by the next or previous segment.

The part I'm mostly struggling with is incorporating the line length in determining $r$ and the centre point. Obviously, it has an effect at any given angle:

[image: Lines]

My ultimate idea is to draw lines between every polygon vertex and calculate the largest semi-circle that will fit inside the polygon along that line. I hope that will give me a good guess at the largest generally that will fit.

**EDIT 2: Specifics...**
[image: Specifc]

I know the blue values, how do I calculate $r$ (and thus $b_{2}$ and $b_{3}$)? ($h$ and $b_{1}$ being trivial). It seems like it should be easy...but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: I had answered your question but withdrew it when I realised you were not necessarily forming a triangle with the three line segments. Which brings me to a question: does the semi-circle have to touch line _segments_ $A$ and $B$, or be tangents of _lines_ $A$ and $B$ (in other words imagine lines $A$ and $B$ extending to infinity)?

Comment: I was able to prove that the expression in the original question is correct. I can provide the proof if necessary. From the proof, by extension, it follows that for $\theta_1, \theta_2 < \pi/2$ the point is always on the line segment $B$, and the tangents are always on the line segments $A$, $C$

Comment: (Changing side names to lower-case ...) The "largest" semi-circle on side $b$ that will always be tangent to (the lines of) sides $a$ and $b$ is in fact the **only** such semi-circle. (Your formula for the radius is correct.) If $a$ is "very short" and cannot reach the "theoretical tangent point" of that semi-circle, then no semi-circle will do. (Likewise for $c$.) So, you must have $$a \geq a_1 = r \frac{\cos\theta_1}{\sin\theta_1} = b\frac{\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2} \quad\text{and}\quad c \geq c_1 = b\frac{\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2}$$

Comment: Are the ends of the segments A and C arbitrary? It would make more sense to have them end where they meet so you wouldn't have this problem. In any case your solution is always correct since it only depends on B and the two angles.

Comment: I expanded on the problem a bit to explain further what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, $P'$ and $Q'$ are projections of $P$ and $Q$ onto $\overline{AC}$; and $P''$ is the reflection of $P$ in that segment. $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{P''Q}$, and $S$ completes the rectangle $\square P'Q'QS$.

By the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem), we're guaranteed that $\angle QPP''\cong\angle P''KM$, so that the sine of that angle can be written in two ways:

> $$\frac{|QS|}{|PQ|} = \frac{|P''M|}{r}
> \quad\to\quad
> r = \frac{|PQ||P''M|}{|QS|} = \frac{|PQ|\cdot\frac12|P''Q|}{|P'Q'|} = \frac{|PQ||P''Q|}{2\,|P'Q'|}
> \tag{$\star$}$$

In terms of provided parameters, we have
$$\begin{align}
|P'Q'| &= |AC|-(|AP'|+|Q'C|) \\[4pt]
&= b - \left(a \cos\theta_1 + c\cos\theta_2\right) \tag{1}\\[6pt]
|PQ|^2 &= |P'Q'|^2 + |PS|^2 = |P'Q'|^2 + (|PP'|-|QQ'|)^2 \\[4pt]
&= |P'Q'|^2 + \left(a \sin\theta_1-c\sin\theta_2\right)^2 \tag{2}\\[6pt]
|P''Q|^2 &= |P'Q'|^2 + |P''S|^2 = |P'Q'|^2 + (|PP'|+|QQ'|)^2 \\[4pt]
&= |P'Q'|^2 + \left(a \sin\theta_1+c\sin\theta_2\right)^2 \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Now, one readily shows that

> Point $P$, respectively $Q$, is a point of tangency when
>   $$
> a = b\;\frac{\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2} , \quad\text{resp.}\quad
> c = b\;\frac{\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2} \tag{$\star\star$} $$
>
> For computational purposes in $(\star)$, lengths $a$ and $c$ should be taken no larger than the values given in $(\star\star)$.

Here are some examples of the results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last two have the same semicircle, since it was computed from the same maximal values of $a$ and $c$ from $(5)$.

Comment: I haven't got back to working on this, but out of interest - what did you use to make these diagrams?

Comment: @Kyudos: I use [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org) for my diagrams.

Comment: Looking at this further - if a and b are both shorter than the tangential points, P and Q are on the circle and the centre is on line AC and thus I can find r. However, how to solve if only one line (say AP) is shorter than its tangential point? P is on the circle, the centre is on AC but there will be a different tangential point on CQ?

Comment: @Kyudos: Equation $(\star)$ gives the radius in all viable cases. Viability is determined by whether $a$ and $c$ are no larger than the values calculated in $(\star\star)$.

Comment: Thanks - think I'm getting to grips with it! Thanks for the GeoGebra tip too...really cool and useful program!

Comment: @Kyudos: In retrospect, there's a bit of geometry overload in my solution. [@robert's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3587726/409) has a cleaner approach via the Law of Cosines. The elimination step, while indeed cumbersome, happens to be equivalent to $(\star)$. ... In any case ... The center of the circle is simply the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ with the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{PQ}$; this is true regardless of whether $P$ or $Q$ are tangent points, which is why the same formula $(\star)$ always works (for viable cases).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit 2:

$b_1=a\cdot cos(\alpha)$ and $r=b_3\cdot sin(\beta)$. Hence $r^2=b_3^2\cdot sin^2(\beta)$

Let $k=b_1+b_2$. Then, from the Cosine Rule: $r^2=a^2+k^2-2\cdot a\cdot k\cdot cos(\alpha)$

Equating the two expressions for $r^2$, and collecting terms around $k$, gives 
$$cos^2(\beta)\cdot k^2-2(a\cdot cos(\alpha)-b\cdot sin^2(\beta))\cdot k+a^2-b^2\cdot sin^2(\beta)=0$$

which can be solved for $k$ using the quadratic formula (it gets quite cumbersome!). Of course this gives two values, but in the example I tried, one could be easily eliminated since it was negative.

Having found $k=b_1+b_2$, $b_3$ can be readily calculated, and hence $r$.

As indicated above, I only tested this once, setting up the situation in Geogebra, measuring the angles, and drawing a circle to fit. The calculated radius and measured radius were in agreement, so hopefully this is of some use.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I set this up in GeoGebra and it works out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line from
the intersection of
sides A and C
is the angle bisector
because of the two
perpendiculars of
length r.